# Why does my render look like one channel?

Tags: rendering

Pretty new to Blender. Using version 3.6.4.

I downloaded this model as a Blender file from a third party: https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/microphone-shure-55-3ds-free/1008238

When viewing the material preview in the viewport, it looks fine. But viewing the render preview or rendering it produces a monochrome alpha-channel-looking result. I'm using the Cycle renderer and can't find any setting that would explain this.

Why might this happen?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This isn't actually the alpha channel being shown, though it looks like it. The model is over exposed.

I downloaded the file you linked and under the world settings you can see the strength of environmental texture is being multiplied by 2.

Setting that to something lower, like 0.2, gives more reasonable results:
[image: Rendered microphone with lower world value]

Comment: Thanks for that! I adjusted that value down, and it did improve the tonal range. But the image is still chunky, as yours still is. Why is it so speckled? That's really the issue I'm raising, not the tonal range.

Comment: Ah, now I see that there are separate sample and denoise controls for the render and the viewport, which prevail even if you select "render preview" for the viewport. Not really intuitive, but I think I have it sorted at this point.

Comment: Take at a look at the [docs for denoising](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/sampling.html#denoising)

I strongly recommend turning denoising on for both viewport and render which will help smooth the image and remove the speckle.

Comment: Thanks @Patrick. I do need to read up on noise and where it comes from in Blender. It seems odd to have it occur by default.